# NetworkManger on KDE cannot edit a connection

Tags: network-manager, kde5

on my KDE neon(Ubuntu 16.04 and Plasma 5.9.5) with  the NetworkManager cannot edit the connection, that means that the NetworkManager cannot save the password to the connection, but it can connect to unencrypted networks. How I can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With me, the only way I managed it was to "**Store password for all users (not encrypted)**" in the "**Wi-Fi Security**" tab and in the "**General configuration**" tab I selected "**all users may connect to this network**"